# Find the lines for which the matrix of partial derivatives is singular

Tags: calculus, vector-fields, gradient-descent

Let $f(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ that belongs to $C^{\infty}$-class, denote $H = \begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{\partial^2f(x,y)}{\partial x^2} & \frac{\partial^2f(x,y)}{\partial x\partial y} \\
\frac{\partial^2f(x,y)}{\partial x\partial y} & \frac{\partial^2f(x,y)}{\partial y^2}
  \end{bmatrix}$.

The picture below illustrates the gradients of $f(x, y)$ with the step of $0.5$. The vector comes from the point where gradient is calculated.

1. It's claimed that there exists a straight line (more than one) along which $H$ is singular. Find every line and its slope $a$ (as in $y = ax + b$).
2. Is it true that there are points where the gradient would not be equal to zero, but starting from which it's impossible to reach the minimum using a gradient descent?

I'd appreciate the hints. [image: gradients]

Comment: A good place to start looking might be the points at which the gradient vanishes. If the Hessian vanishes there, what happens if you follow the diagonal line joining two of these points?

Comment: Rigorously speaking, since the values of the gradient are provided only for a discrete grid, I guess we can modify the function outside the grid  points assuring that $H$ is singular not along a line, but along an image curve which is close to a line with respect to a Hausdorff metric.